# Redirecting one step up in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have a nested form with a url like:

```
/organizations/1/reports/new
```

After a report is submitted, I want to redirect the client to:

```
/organizations/1/reports
```

Typically, I would accomplish this by redirecting the user with `transitionToRoute`. However, in this case I do not how access to the organization's id. (Or at least, I don't know how to access that information. It is in the URL, but I'm unsure how to pull it down.) As an alternative, is it possible to redirect the client one step up from the current url, so that `/organizations/1/reports/new` would be redirected to `/organizations/1/reports`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.transitionToRoute('reports')` from the controller or `this.transitionTo('reports')` from the route.

Comment: Perfect. I had been trying `this.transitionToRoute('organization.report', @content)`. Removing the `@content` does the trick: `this.transitionToRoute('organization.report')`.

Comment: Yeah, if you are hopping up levels you can leave out the resource and it'll just essentially pop off the deeper routes (aka all of the resources stay intact).

Comment: Magic is awesome once you know how to use it.